# Как вернуть строку которая была добавлена mysql

Tags: mysql

Всем привет! Сейчас использую процедуру такого типа :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `createUser`(
IN _name VARCHAR(100),
IN _surname VARCHAR(100),
IN _email VARCHAR(100),
IN _password VARCHAR(512)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `api`.`users`(name, surname, email, password, created_at, updated_at)
VALUE (_name, _surname, _email, _password, now(), now());

SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = _email;
END
```

мне кажется что `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = _email;` это лишняя нагрузка. Возможно ли вернуть всю строку которая была добавлена без запроса SELECT? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в данном случае работать будет

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createUser`(
IN _name VARCHAR(100),
IN _surname VARCHAR(100),
IN _email VARCHAR(100),
IN _password VARCHAR(512)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE _now Datetime DEFAULT 0;
SET _now = _now();

INSERT INTO `api`.`users`(name, surname, email, password, created_at, updated_at)
VALUE (_name, _surname, _email, _password, _now, _now);

SELECT _name, _surname, _email, _password, _now, _now;
END
```

но всё таки лучше брать данные из таблицы это гарантирует возврат записанных данных, а не отправленных на сохранение.

Comment: странно что система которой уже 25 лет не умеет говорить "Окей, чувак, я успешно добавил данные в таблицу"...... Спасибо за помощь, то есть лучше все же запрашивать таблицу для подтверждения?!

Comment: допустим вы на входе имеете строчку varchar(100) а в таблицу урезалось и записалось varchar(10) чисто гипотетически что вы получите на выходе в различных вариантах? думайте и решайте сами. ведь триггеры никто не отменял

Comment: ну как говориться "семь раз отмерь, один отрежь" =) Всегда лучше проверить на данные на корректность.

Comment: именно. так спокойнее жить. Я к примеру и вовсе не возвращаю эти данные на инсерте только id. А потом по надобности запрашиваю весь по id отдельно, и не беспокоюсь про производительность в этом месте. Это единичный инсерт и это говорит о том что нагрузки на нем нет и вовсе. Если б была нагрузка то вы бы пользовались пакетным сохранением.

Comment: это как купить авто на миллионы и думать о расходе на бензин. Экономте там где это эффективно

Comment: ну да, у меня есть еще один вопрос по mysql, если не сложно, можете подсказать? Возможно в чат или создать могу новый вопрос, хоть он короткий достаточно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108314/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and--).